# laravel socialite get google access token from google Authorization Code

Tags: android, laravel, jwt, google-authentication, laravel-socialite

I've an Android app that use google authentication to register users
and I am using `laravel  socillite` for the  authentication

I can't get this to work because the android app send me an authorization code not the access token and I do't know how can I get the access token from that `Authorization Code` 
From my understanding I should do the following:

- get the `access token` from android `Authorization Code`
- use `Socialite::driver('google')->userFromToken($token)` to get user data
- send `JWT` token to the android device 
  Can anyone explain how can I do this using `laravel socillite`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I did solve this by using a `getAccessTokenResponse` function as the followoing:

```
$access_token = Socialite::driver($provider)->getAccessTokenResponse($token);
$user = Socialite::driver($provider)->userFromToken($access_token['access_token']);
```